# how can I add a Maven library to an ant project using netbeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, ant

I have a program I have written using netbeans it is in the standard ant format.

There is a library I want to use that is in maven format.

How can I install the Maven library into the ant project

Answer (score 0):

You can go to maven central (https:/msearch.maven.org) or other repo site and search for the library.
Download it and add it to the project as you would normally do.